# How can I get the type of a JSON value in Presto?

Tags: sql, json, presto, trino

I have a JSON string that I am querying with Presto and I want to aggregate by the types of values. To do this I need to get the value type. Specifically, for JSON like:

```json
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": "a",
  "c": true,
  "d": [ 1 ],
  "e": { "f": "g" },
}
```

I would like to get the value at `$.a` is an integer, the value at `$.b` is a string, etc. (The information doesn't need to be nested so it would be good enough to know that `$.d` is an array and `$.e` is an object).

`typeof` appears to return only varchar or json, depending on how you extract JSON from a string:

```sql
SELECT
    typeof(json_extract(j, '$.a')),
    typeof(json_extract_scalar(j, '$.a'))
FROM (SELECT '{"a":1,"b":"a","c":true,"d":[1]}' AS j);
```

gives me:

```
_col0   _col1
json    varchar(32)
```

How can I determine the JSON value type for one of these fields?

Comment: There seems to be no function for that. The closest you can get is [`is_json_scalar()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#is_json_scalar) which allows you to distinguish between array and scalar, but doesn't distinguish between an integer and a string.

Answer (score 1):

- `json_extract` gets a value in a JSON string as the `json` type.
- `json_format` takes a `json` value and converts it back to a JSON string.

I think you can hack these two things together to get the type of a value at a position by examining the formatted string.

```
CASE
    WHEN substr(value, 1, 1) = '{'  THEN 'object'
    WHEN substr(value, 1, 1) = '['  THEN 'array'
    WHEN substr(value, 1, 1) = '"'  THEN 'string'
    WHEN substr(value, 1, 1) = 'n'  THEN 'null'
    WHEN substr(value, 1, 1) = 't'  THEN 'boolean'
    WHEN substr(value, 1, 1) = 'f'  THEN 'boolean'
    ELSE 'number'
END AS t
```

(where value is `json_format(json_extract(json_string, '$.your_json_path'))`)

Here's an example:

```sql
SELECT obj, value,
   CASE
       WHEN substr(value, 1, 1) = '{'  THEN 'object'
       WHEN substr(value, 1, 1) = '['  THEN 'array'
       WHEN substr(value, 1, 1) = '"'  THEN 'string'
       WHEN substr(value, 1, 1) = 'n'  THEN 'null'
       WHEN substr(value, 1, 1) = 't'  THEN 'boolean'
       WHEN substr(value, 1, 1) = 'f'  THEN 'boolean'
       ELSE 'number'
   END AS t
FROM (
    SELECT obj, json_format(json_extract(obj, '$.a')) AS value
    FROM (
        VALUES
          ('{"a":1}'),
          ('{"a":2.5}'),
          ('{"a":"abc"}'),
          ('{"a":true}'),
          ('{"a":false}'),
          ('{"a":null}'),
          ('{"a":[1]}'),
          ('{"a":{"h":"w"}}')
    ) AS t (obj)
)
```

Which produces this result:

```
obj                  value            t
{"a":1}              1                number
{"a":2.5}            2.5              number
{"a":"abc"}          "abc"            string
{"a":true}           true             boolean
{"a":false}          false            boolean
{"a":null}           null             null
{"a":[1]}            [1]              array
{"a":{"h":"w"}}      {"h":"w"}        object
```